# Adding user to blackboard using ColdFusion

Tags: xml, web-services, coldfusion, blackboard

I'm able to create the authentication session successfully but I'm receiving the following [WSFW000]null error when attempting to add a user.

This is the package I'm sending:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soappackage">
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAPENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAPENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAPENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security SOAPENV:mustunderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:Timestamp xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Created xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-03-16T13:18:56Z</wsse:Created>
      </wsse:Timestamp>
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">session</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">c5bc911f5632441d96776470653f6ccd</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAPENV:Header>
  <SOAPENV:Body>
    <ns1:saveUser xmlns:ns1="http://user.ws.blackboard">
      <ns1:user>
        <ns1:extendedInfo>
          <ns1:givenName>Mary</ns1:givenName>
          <ns1:familyName>Mary</ns1:familyName>
        </ns1:extendedInfo>
        <ns1:name>t1245op2sss24zx</ns1:name>
        <ns1:password>test</ns1:password>
        <ns1:insRoles>STAFF</ns1:insRoles>
        <ns1:systemRoles>USER</ns1:systemRoles>
      </ns1:user>
    </ns1:saveUser>
  </SOAPENV:Body>
</SOAPENV:Envelope>
</cfsavecontent>
```

This is the call:

```
<cfhttp url="https://nu-test.blackboard.com/webapps/ws/services/User.WS" method="POST" timeout="20" >
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Type" value="application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Accept" value="application/soap+xml, multipart/related">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="User-Agent" value="xWeb:ColdFusion">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Connection" value="keep-alive">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="SOAPAction" value="saveUser">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Length" value="#len(trim(soappackage))#">
    <cfhttpparam type="BODY" value="#trim(soappackage)#">
</cfhttp>
```

This is the response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <soapenv:Code>
        <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
      </soapenv:Code>
      <soapenv:Reason>
        <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">[WSFW000]null</soapenv:Text>
      </soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Detail />
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: you're probably going to need to post some more information, what do the docs say that it expects.  also since it's a `https` request, the certificate might need adding to the keystore?

Comment: Thanks Jarede, I'm in contact with their "support" team but unfortunately they don't have any useful documentation. I'm waiting to hear back from them. I have other calls already working with https. The saveUser method is the only one returning this error.